# Occurrence typing with polymorphic union types

Tags: racket, typed-racket

Suppose I want to convert the following untyped code into typed racket. These functions are inspired by SICP where they show how a data structure can be constructed purely from functions.

```
(define (make-pair x y)
    (lambda (c)
        (cond
            ((= c 1) x)
            ((= c 2) y)
            (error "error in input, should be 1 or 2"))))

(define (first p) (p 1))
(define (second p) (p 2))
```

To convert it straight to typed racket, the return value of the `make-pair` function seems to be `(: make-pair (All (A B) (-> A B (-> Number (U A B)))))`. And following this, the type of `first` should be `(: first (All (A B) (-> (-> Number (U A B)) A)))`. However, while implementing the function we can't call `(p 1)` directly now because we need some sort of occurrence typing to make sure `first` returns only of type `A`. Changing the return type of `first` to `(U A B)` works but then the burden of occurrence typing goes on the user and not in the API. So in this scenario how can we use occurrence typing inside `first` (that is, how to use a predicate for type variable `A`) so that we can safely return only the first component of the pair?

UPDATE

I tried an approach which differs a bit from above and requires the predicates for `A` and `B` to be supplied as arguments to `make-pair` function. Below is the code:

```
#lang typed/racket


(define-type FuncPair (All (A B) (List (-> Number (U A B)) (-> A Boolean) (-> B Boolean))))

(: make-pair (All (A B) (-> A B (-> A Boolean) (-> B Boolean) (FuncPair A B))))
(define (make-pair x y x-pred y-pred)
    (list
        (lambda ([c : Number])
            (cond
                ((= c 1) x)
                ((= c 2) y)
                (else (error "Wrong input!"))))
        x-pred
        y-pred))

(: first (All (A B) (-> (FuncPair A B) Any)))
(define (first p)
    (let ([pair-fn (car p)]
          [fn-pred (cadr p)])
        (let ([f-value (pair-fn 1)])
            (if (fn-pred f-value)
                f-value
                (error "Cannot get first value in pair")))))
```

However, this fails in the check `(fn-pred f-value)` condition with error `expected: A
  given: (U A B) in: f-value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the untyped code at the start of your question, it seems like a pair of A and B is a function that given `1`, gives back A, and given `2`, gives back B. The way to express this type of function is with a `case->` type:

```
#lang typed/racket

(define-type (Pairof A B)
  (case-> [1 -> A] [2 -> B]))
```

The accessors can be defined the same way as your original untyped code, just by adding type annotations:

```
(: first : (All (A B) [(Pairof A B) -> A]))
(define (first p) (p 1))
(: second : (All (A B) [(Pairof A B) -> B]))
(define (second p) (p (ann 2 : 2)))
```

The type of the constructor should be:

```
(: make-pair : (All (A B) [A B -> (Pairof A B)]))
```

But the constructor doesn't quite work as-is. One thing wrong with it is that your `else` clause is missing the `else` part of it. Fixing that gives you:

```
(: make-pair : (All (A B) [A B -> (Pairof A B)]))
(define (make-pair x y)
  (lambda (c)
    (cond
      [(= c 1) x]
      [(= c 2) y]
      [else (error "error in input, should be 1 or 2")])))
```

This is almost right, and if typed racket were awesome enough, it would be. Typed racket treats `equal?` specially for occurrence typing, but it doesn't do the same thing for `=`. Changing `=` to `equal?` fixes it.

```
(: make-pair : (All (A B) [A B -> (Pairof A B)]))
(define (make-pair x y)
  (lambda (c)
    (cond
      [(equal? c 1) x]
      [(equal? c 2) y]
      [else (error "error in input, should be 1 or 2")])))
```

Ideally occurrence typing should work with `=`, but perhaps the fact that things like `(= 2 2.0)` return true makes that both harder to implement and less useful.